# How to change progressbar background color using javascript

Tags: javascript, ext.net

I was looking for how to change the ext.net progressbar background color using JavaScript. possibly adding a CSS class to the progressbar from JavaScript.

I have tried adding a css class but failed. Actually I cant find the function which will facilitate me to add the CSS class to it.

any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**javascript:**

```
 function ShowProgressBar(progressBar, progressValue, message) {
            progressBar.show();
            progressBar.updateProgress(progressValue, message);
//need to add the css class here something like progressBar.addClass('green-bar')
        }
```

**CSS:**

```
    .green-bar{
        background:#008000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i have solved the issue. just need to change the CSS class name.

**CSS:**

```
   .green-bar .x-progress-bar{
        background:#008000;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
progressBar.addClass('green-bar'); //obviously i have removed the added css class after use.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **add listener** that calls [update function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-update),

```
listeners: { 
    update: function (obj, val) {
        obj.getElelement().child("PROGRESSBAR_NAME", true).style.backgroundColor = "#FF00CC";
    }
}
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo Example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/ProgressBar2.html#Ext-ProgressBar)**</kbd>

Read this **[Progressbar](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar)** Documentation help you

Comment: thanks I have understand it. but don't mind can you please show me a ext.net sample instead of extjs.

Comment: actually i m not working on ext but i know i apply style via HTML DOM manipulation.